# Time to event analysis - median (IQR) is <75% experience event

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier, interquartile

I am plotting the Kaplan-Meier survivor function for time to event & will estimate the median survival. I want to present this with the IQR. If the resultant KM looks something like the below & <75% experience the event, how is it best to present the IQR?

eg, for the red line, would we say median survival 45 (IQR 15-*)? Or is there a better way to present this?

[image: Image taken from a google search under a CC BY-NC-ND 4.0 licence]

NB: KM taken from paper with appropriate licence: CC BY-NC-ND 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases were only few subjects experience the event, calculating a median (= 50% survival probability) might not be possible. Because for most subjects the event hasn´t occured yet, you can´t give put a time on the 50% survival probability. Thats why you are not getting a second boundary for the red curve and probably no estimates for the blue curve.

However you could look at **75% survival** probability. The following code gives you 75% and 50% survival probability with 95% confidence interval:

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df)
quantile(fit, probs = c(0.25, 0.5))
```